Need to display form details before updating the form
I am trying to create an e commerce website. I just want to display form details on the
form itself before updating it. I am unable to do that. I want to know how to display the details on the form.
I have created one database test.db with three tables - Brand, Category and Addproduct. I have created forms separately. Main.py has all the functions for updating the database.
Models.py: 
class Brand(db.Model):
    __tablename__ =  'brand'
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30),nullable=False, unique=True)


class Category(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30),nullable=False, unique=True)


class Addproduct(db.Model):
    #__tablename__ = 'addproduct'
    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    name:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(80),nullable=False, unique=True)
    price:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer,nullable=False)
    discount:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer,default=0)
    stock:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer,nullable=False)
    colors:Mapped[Text] = mapped_column(Text,nullable=False)
    description:Mapped[Text] = mapped_column(Text,nullable=False
    category_id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, 
    db.ForeignKey('category.id'),nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship('Category',backref=db.backref('category', lazy=True))

    brand_id:Mapped[int]= mapped_column(Integer, 
    db.ForeignKey('brand.id'),nullable=False)
    brand = db.relationship('Brand',backref=db.backref('brand', lazy=True))

    image_1:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False, default='image1.jpg')
    image_2:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False, default='image2.jpg')
    image_3:Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, nullable=False, default='image3.jpg')


Forms.py:
class AddProducts(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name',validators=[DataRequired()])
    price = IntegerField('Price',validators=[DataRequired()])
    discount = IntegerField('Discount', default=0)
    stock = IntegerField('Stock',validators=[DataRequired()])
    brands = QuerySelectField('Add a brand', query_factory=brandchoices)
    categories = QuerySelectField('Add a category', query_factory=categorychoices)
    colors = TextAreaField('Colors',validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description',validators=[DataRequired()])
    image_1= FileField('First Image', validators= 
    [FileAllowed(['jpg','jpeg','png','gif'])])
    image_2= FileField('Second Image', validators= 
    [FileAllowed(['jpg','jpeg','png','gif'])])
    image_3= FileField('Third Image', validators= 
    [FileAllowed(['jpg','jpeg','png','gif'])])
    Submit = SubmitField('Add Product')

main.py:

@app.route('/updateprod/<int:id>', methods=['POST','GET'])
def updateproduct(id):
    product = Addproduct.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = AddProducts()
    brands = Brand.query.all()
    categories = Category.query.all()
    brand = request.form.get('brands')
    category = request.form.get('categories')
    if request.method =="POST":
        product.name = form.name.data 
        product.price = form.price.data
        product.discount = form.discount.data
        product.stock = form.stock.data 
        product.colors = form.colors.data
        product.description = form.description.data
        product.category_id = category
        product.brand_id = brand
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.name.data = product.name,
        form.price.data = product.price,
        form.discount.data = product.discount,
        form.stock.data = product.stock,
        form.colors.data = product.colors,
        form.description.data = product.description,
        brand = product.brand.name,
        category = product.category.name
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('products/updateproduct.html', form=form, all_products = 
    product, brands=brands, categories=categories)

